# Tiptoi Ravensburger - How to add new audio files?

Tags: files, games

[Tiptoi Ravensburger](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiptoi) learning game: How can I add new audio files to the [Tiptoi pen](https://www.ravensburger.de/entdecken/ravensburger-marken/tiptoi/tiptoi-stift/index.html) in Ubuntu Linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How to add new audio files in Ubuntu Linux:

1. Download the free audio files manually from the page of the individual product, click on "Audiodatei manuell herunterladen", e.g. from [Weltatlas book](https://www.ravensburger.de/produkte/kinderbuecher/tiptoi/tiptoi-mein-grosser-weltatlas-32911/index.html), and another right click on the "Klicken Sie mit der rechten Maustaste auf folgenden Link: [Audiodatei zu ...](https://cdn.ravensburger.de/db/applications/WWW%20Weltatlas.gme)" from the opened [overlayed window](https://www.ravensburger.de/produkte/kinderbuecher/tiptoi/tiptoi-mein-grosser-weltatlas-32911/index.html#tiptoiDownloadContainer) and with "save links as" to your hard drive or directly to the connected Tiptoi (see 3.).
2. Connect the Tiptoi with the USB cable, turn it on. It will appear as new drive "tiptoi" in your file browser (e.g. Nautilus, Nemo, Thunar).
3. Transfer the downloaded audio files from your harddrive to your tiptoi drive without changing the name (e.g. in your file browser).
4. Disconnect the Tiptoi.
5. Restart the Tiptoi.
   [Instructions in German.](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tiptoi)

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the tiptoi manager from [tiptoi.com](http://www.tiptoi.com)
2. Extract the files from install.exe to any directory `{~/tiptoi/}`
3. Go to `{~/tiptoi/}application/`
4. - In terminal:

     ```
     java -jar tiptoi-x.x.x-jar-with-dependencies.jar
     ```
   - or Nemo: right click on jar file > open with java
5. Enjoy

Comment: How to extract the exe? Using `unzip` on https://ssl-static.ravensburger.de/db/Installer/install.exe results into "cannot find zipfile directory".

Comment: Installed it with `wine`. There no jar-files included. The "MonoBleedingEdge"-directory tells us that this is a .NET application.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install wine from the repository
2. Download the tiptoi manager from tiptoi.com
3. Connect the tiptoi pen to a USB port
4. Open a terminal and navigate to the directory where the tiptoi manager was stored
5. Enter wine install.exe
6. Follow the instructions of the installer
7. At the end of the installation start the tiptoi manager
8. Download the desired files

Comment: Didn't work for me.